# FQL "DISTINCT" method

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am grabbing friends' statuses using STREAM table and FQL. I want to get back ONLY one status per friend, but FQL doesn't support "normal" SQL operators like `DISTINCT`. Any ideas how to make such a distinct based on `actor_id` column?

my FQL:

```
"SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type=\'newsfeed\')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot use distinct keyword in FQL (`enables you to use a SQL-style interface to query the data exposed by the Graph API`)

You have to handle it in your application. Loop through your results and store each `friend_id` as a key in an associative array and store the values (Based on the timestamp)